# fid of a default image in Drupal 7 - managed_file field. What to set default value of fid to?

Tags: php, image, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I've got this image upload field in Drupal 7 with:

```
'#default_value' => variable_get('default_img_fid', ''),
```

However, I'm not sure how to set that variable so that when Drupal senses there is no uploaded image and the form is submitted, it will gather the information for the default image. I've placed the image in the sites/default/files/images folder.

What do I set:

```
variable_set('default_img_fid', '?????');
```

to?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file doesn't have a `fid` until it's in the `file_managed` table. If you've uploaded the file manually then you'll also need to register it manually in the `file_managed` table.

Just take one of the other rows in there as a base example and work from there, once the record's been inserted you'll have the `fid` you need :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer. I was hoping there was an automated way to do it. This worked though.